# Controlling the font of the content of an HTML Table in iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I am using the most recent DLLs and trying to render HTML fragments into a PDF document using the following code:

```
    Private Function ReadHtml(ByVal text As String) As Paragraph
        Dim par = NewParagraph()
        Try
            Dim htmlText = Server.HtmlDecode(text)
            If Not htmlText.StartsWith("<") Then
                htmlText = "<span>" & htmlText & "</span>"
            End If
            Using reader As New IO.StringReader(htmlText)
                Dim mh As New MyHandler()
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(mh, reader)
                'use mh.elements
                For Each element In mh.Elements
                    Dim list = TryCast(element, List)
                    If list IsNot Nothing Then
                        element = Clone(list)
                    End If

                    par.Add(element)
                Next
                setFont(par, m_rowFont)


            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Exception in ReadHtml using: '" & text & "'")
        End Try
        Return par

    End Function
```

When this function returns, I take the paragraph and insert it into the PDF.  The problem I am having is that while I can set the font in an outer div, and the resulting PDF will render that correctly, if I include an HTML table inside of the div where I've set the font, everything inside of the table renders using the Page's default font.

How do I control the font of the table content?

Answer (score -1):

Your Html in font-size and font-family remove.

```
    public string ConvertPdfHtml(string html)
    {
        html = CleanStyleAttribute(html, "font-family");
        html = CleanStyleAttribute(html, "font-size");
        ....
        return html;
    }

    private string CleanStyleAttribute(string html, string styleAttributeName)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(html, styleAttributeName + "(?>:(.*?);)","");
    }
```

Comment: How does removing the font attributes solve the problem?  Who said I was even setting font information in the HTML?  Have you ever used iTextSharp?